# Opacity into Cloud Carousel

Tags: jquery, cloud, carousel

I'm working with Cloud Carousel and I would like to put some opacity. for example, if i have 5 img, the 2 at the back get an opacity of 0, those in middle get an opacity of 0.5 and the one in the front get an opacity of 1. I would like this to be changing dynamically.

Here is the link of Cloud Carousel: http://www.professorcloud.com/mainsite/carousel.htm

Here is my script.js :

```
$("#carousel1").CloudCarousel(
    {
        xPos: 460,
        yPos: 0,
        altBox: $("#alt-text"),
        titleBox: $("#title-text"),
        autoRotate: 'no',
        bringToFront: 'true',
        minScale: .1,
        reflHeight:30,
        reflGap:0,
        xRadius:600,
        yRadius:150,
        reflOpacity: 0
    }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

In the plugin script, find the line:

```
img.style.zIndex = "" + (scale * 100)>>0;
```

and try adding a line below this line with this content:

```
img.style.opacity = scale;
```

Answer (score 0):

Find the line :

```
 h = img.height = item.orgHeight * scale;
```

in the function :

```
 this.updateAll
```

and add the following in the next line:

```
$(img).css({'opacity':scale * scale * 1.2});
```